# Output XAML Grid in to HTML

Tags: c#, html, silverlight, xaml

I have a Grid which shows a layout for an invoice.

What I would like to do is output the invoice to a HTML webpage.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972129%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) MS sample...it includes a XAML to HTML converter.